# How to reuse same .onion address with Tor ephemeral hidden services (python)?

Tags: python

I'm establishing an ephemeral hidden service via Tor, but I wish to reuse the same .onion address. I know to do this I must presist the same private-key every time I run the hidden service, but how do I do this?

I'm basically following the [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/over_the_river.html) documentation for python, but they don't tell you know to presist your private-key, just how to establish a hidden service.

I could use a non-ephemeral hidden service, but I would like be able to run my .py file to establish a hidden service via usb flash drive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look [here at the official docs](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.create_ephemeral_hidden_service) ? It explicitly says, that key *can be provided* on creation. Of course, if you've *already* created an *ephemeral* hidden service, then no key or other stuff can be fetched, *because it's the very meaning of it's ephemerical nature*. Create your RSA1024 key and use it, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this.

```
from stem import control
controller = control.Controller.from_port(address=TOR_CONTROL_HOST, port=TOR_CONTROL_PORT)
controller.authenticate()
key = 'raw-base64-of-the-rsa-1024-key-here'
onion = controller.create_ephemeral_hidden_service(ports=80, discard_key=True, await_publication=True, key_type='RSA1024', key_content=key)
if not onion.is_ok():
    raise Exception('Failed to publish onion.')
```

In my case loading the contents of 'key' from a file and if it wasn't there then generating a new one from tor itself by reading the results of publishing a totally ephemeral hidden service.

```
onion = controller.create_ephemeral_hidden_service(ports=80, discard_key=False, await_publication=True)
if not onion.is_ok():
    raise Exception('Failed to publish onion.')
for o in onion:
    if o != "OK":
        k, v = o.split('=', 1)
        if k == "PrivateKey":
            do_stuff_to_save_private_key(v)
```