# How do I reuse the onion address of a hidden service

Tags: onion-services, python, stem

I first want to generate a service and save the private key for reuse if one hasn't already been generated and saved, and if one has been generated and saved I want to be able to load it again if possible, so I can reuse the onion address within my program.

Also I'm programming this with python and you can see my program so far if you'd like to have a look.

[program link](https://github.com/Footsiefat/Tiresias_Backend/blob/main/tiresias.py)

Answer (score 0):

You're using stem's [`create_ephemeral_hidden_service()`](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.create_ephemeral_hidden_service), which allows you to specify the key to use for your onion service with the `key_type` and `key_content` arguments. You can either create the key manually before you first run the program, or the first time you run the program, you can allow `create_ephemeral_hidden_service()` to generate the key (make sure the `discard_key` option is `False`), parse the response from tor, save the `PrivateKey` field in the response, and then re-use this key in the future.

There is a code example here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/10483

Comment: I already had a look at that example sadly. The second example which allows me to get the generated keys didn't work. The first part only returns the hostname/onion address rather than the keys.

Comment: Okay you'll need to create the key manually then. I would have tor create a new onion service, copy the key, delete the service, and then re-use this key in the Python code.